# Filter DateTime with ExecSQL

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I'm applying this filter:

```
var date = new DateTime(2019, 06, 20).ToUniversalTime().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
MAPITable mt = session.Stores.MAPITable;
mt.Item = inbox.Items;

var records = mt.ExecSQL($"select Subject, EntryID from Inbox Where \"urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived\" > {date}");
```

I'm having this exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in ConsoleApplication1.exe

Additional information: Unsupported operator: /

Should it be possible to do this kind of filter? [With > operator]

Comment: I've tried with 'ReceivedTime' too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the date variable is SQL formatted and encoded in single quotes.

Comment: Hi Dmitry,

Thank you for your answer, I was formatted to brazilian date format, so wasn't working. I've Changed the format and then works.